# Discrete maths: proof by contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Hi I'm new to discrete maths, and I have a prove by contradiction question. For example, say $15$ children together gathered $100$ marbles.

How do I prove by contradiction that some pair of children gathered the same number?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 4):

You begin by assuming that the desired result is false: no two children gathered the same number of marbles. In that case what is the smallest possible number of marbles that they could have gathered altogether? The smallest set of $15$ different non-negative integers is

$$M=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14\}\;;$$

if each child gathered a different number of marbles, they must have gathered at least as are in the set $M$. How many is that? Is that possible if they gathered $100$ marbles altogether?

If the answer to that last question is *no*, you’ve reached the desired contradiction: you’ve shown that it’s impossible for each of them to have gathered a different number of marbles. This of course implies that two of them must have gathered the same number.

Comment: Nicely outlined, Brian +1, without actually proving it.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering,but is there a formula or something to do this out. i read about the generalized pigeon hole principle. wonder if it's ok to use it?

Comment: @sher: No, you won’t use a formula for this one (except possibly to calculate the sum of the numbers in $M$), and you don’t need any form of the pigeonhole principle. My answer is almost a full proof; you just need to fill in some details and finish it off. Do you understand the principle behind proof by contradiction? You assume that what you want to prove is actually false and derive a contradiction from that.

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Brian's answer, to outline the general approach when writing a proof by contradiction:

- We have the "givens", which is one or more "knowns" or *premises* that we accept as true (as given). Call them premises $P$.
- We have a conclusion we need to prove: Call this $C$.

So our objective is to show that $P \rightarrow C$. That is, if the premise(s) is/are true, then the conclusion must be true.

A proof by contradiction then explores what would happen if $C$ were to be false, with the aim of finding a contradiction:

We start by assuming $\lnot C.\;$

- "Suppose $P$ is true, and assume it is ***not the case*** that $C$ holds."

  - then $\quad\vdots$
  - then $\quad\vdots$
  - ***Contradiction!*** 
    (Having assumed $\lnot C$, we are led to conclude something that simply CANNOT BE TRUE, given the premises and what we know to be true.)
- Therefore, if $P$ is true, *it cannot be the case* that that our assumption $\lnot C$ is correct; that is, we reject the assumption "NOT C" , in order to avoid a contradiction, and are left, by default, to conclude that it is $C$ which must follow from $P$
- Therefore, $P \rightarrow C$

---

Brian M. Scott has provided a nice strategy for arriving at a contradiction in this particular case.